# Kotlin 1.5.31 undefined methods

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Recently I was unable to compile my app because functions like substringAfter or .let {} gives unresolved reference error

[image]

Upgrading `kotlin-gradle-plugin` to 1.6.0 works fine but jetpack compose doesn't support it.

What cause the unresolved reference in kotlin 1.5.31 in android studio I just don't understand

My gradle looks like

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
```

Comment: This kind of thing can happen when there's some mismatch of Kotlin versions in your project configuration. You might check if there's somewhere else in your project configuration where it still says Kotlin 1.6.0 or some version other than 1.5.31. Or if you have a project dependency that is using Kotlin 1.6.

Comment: How to i fix such issue @Tenfour04

Comment: I’m just guessing. Look through your dependencies and see if one uses Kotlin 1.6 and downgrade it if necessary. You might have to find the web sites for those dependencies to check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compose as of `December 1, 2021` supports kotlin 1.6.0 so I updated my dependencies [LINK](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler#1.1.0-beta04)

`kotlin-plugin` to `1.6.0`

`compose_version` to `1.1.0-beta04`